# Which desktop indexer indexes xml file content?

Tags: software-rec, search

My favorite indexer [doesn't have this capability](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=615857), and I'm looking for an alternative that does.

Comment: Are you a programmer? You could attempt to submit a patch to them :)

Answer (score 1):

links which promise xml indexing to be possible:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0024039.htm

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-matters10/index.html

http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2010/06/16/indexing-xml/

While the question is for Desktop search/indexing tool with support for xml files, it has been said that Google desktop offers such capability, but recently Google has announced to end the development and support of the tool.

http://rjdudley.com/blog/index.php/2006/12/indexing-and-searching-xml-files-with-google-desktop/